# iphone html custom font duplicates itself

Tags: iphone, html, css, safari, webfonts

I have a simple html h1 title that works fine on desktop browsers but duplicates the font on iOS (Tested on Safari & Mercury Browser)

Preview image: http://d.pr/i/ku1I

The h1 css:

```
.headerInterior h1
{
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  color: #f2085c;
  font-family: 'effBold';
  font-size: 79px;
}
```

Does anyone had the same problem and know a solution for this? 
Any help will be appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

Add this in your CSS class

`font-weight: normal;`

OR

`text-shadow: 0 0 0;`

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the browser tries to *generate* the font weight thats requested if its unavailable already (h1 class in the example has default font-weight set to bold).

For instance, if we are using the following Google Fonts URL:

http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Serif:400,600italic

We have two ways to use this font:

`.first-way{
    font-family: 'PT Serif';
    font-weight: 400;
}`

OR

`.second-way{
    font-family: 'PT Serif';
    font-weight: 600;
    font-style: italic;
}`

Using: `font-weight: normal;` basically defaults to the font-weight of the available font.

Further reading: http://alistapart.com/article/say-no-to-faux-bold